# Conexion a SQL Server desde R

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, r

Estoy tratando de realizar una conexión  a una base de datos en *SQL Server* desde *R*, tengo el servidor `172.16.XXX.XXX`, el nombre de la base de datos `"pnet"`, usuario: `"usrname"`, pwd: `"pwd"`.

Estoy usando la librería de `RODBC`, aquí esta mi código:

```
library('RODBC')
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=172.16.XXX.XXX;database=panet;Uid=usrname; Pwd=pwd; trusted_connection=true')
```

Y me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intenté cambiar el estado de `trusted connection` a `false`, conectarme sin `username` ni `pwd`, e inclusive usar el `odbcConnect(dsn, uid = "", pwd = "", ...)`
 y nada parece funcionar.

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar a lograr esta conexión!!

Comment: José `trusted_connection` espera `yes` o `no` (no `True`o `False`), prueba con el valor `no` y obviamente con un valor válido para el usuario y contraseña.

Comment: Ya funcionó así! Muchas gracias!